# A very simple confusion about "let" when assigning variables

Tags: haskell, ghci

The wikibooks Haskell [page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Variables_and_functions) on variables and functions notes the following:

> Note
>
> The let keyword (a word with a special meaning) lets us define
> variables directly at the GHCi prompt without a source file. This
> looks like:
>
> `Prelude> let area = pi * 5 ^ 2`
>
> Although sometimes convenient,
> assigning variables entirely in GHCi this way is impractical for any
> complex tasks. We will usually want to use saved source files.

but I can just do `area = pi * 5 ^ 2` at the prompt and skip the let. I've also seen this use of let at the prompt in Learn You a Haskell. Why would I use the let, is there something important about it that I'm missing?

Comment: It's just slightly outdated. The `let` used to be required, there was no other way to introduce new names in `ghci`. Now `let` is optional, because it kept tripping up people given that you don't need it in the top level of Haskell files normally.

Answer (score 1):

GHCi evaluates the expression (the whole line) as soon as enter is pressed, and the expression itself cannot be spaned over several lines (to make an expression in GHCi span over multiple lines `:{` and `:}` can be used).

In Haskell, a `let` expression should be followed by `in`. But in **GHCi** the expression is interpreted in the `IO` monad, and a `let` binding with no accompanying `in` statement can be just be followed by an empty line.

Since GHC `8.0.1` it is possible to bind values and functions to names **without `let` statement**.

*Important difference*, however, between these two types of binding and a third type, the monadic bind, is that the monadic bind *a <- exp* is strict, so *exp* is evaluated immediately, while with the `let` form or direct equality form *exp* would not be evaluated immediately.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `let` expression is not followed by `in`; the entire `let ... in ...` is *one* expression. (The use of `let` as part of a `do` block and its related use at as a top-level assignment in GHCi is a separate matter.)

Comment: Yes, correct - let.. in .. is one expression, I didn't mean they are separate ones, but it is always the matter of precise language, thanks for pointing that out.